# Service won't run python srcipt with privileges RASPBIAN JEESIE

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, python, boot, services

I have script in python that need to be run with "sudo" keyword. Everything  because I'm accessing "/dev/mem". Now I need to start this python script on RPi startup. So I create simple service that launch this script it looks like :

```
[Unit]
Description=sendService
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u send.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/pywork
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

it is inside /etc/systemd/system directory. I observe that this script is trying to work properly but it gives me error about my python script (that access to /dev/mem is denied). Same problem I have when I use to run this script using "python3 send.py" commend but when I use "sudo python3 send.py" it works like charm. Does it means that this service run mine program without sudo privileges even if user is set to root ?

Edit:

systemctl status gives

```
● serviceSend.service - sendService
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/serviceSend.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Fri 2018-08-10 10:36:43 UTC; 3min 35s ago
  Process: 1306 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 -u send.py (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1306 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 10 10:36:42 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started sendService.
Aug 10 10:36:43 raspberrypi sudo[1320]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi/pywork ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
Aug 10 10:36:43 raspberrypi sudo[1320]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Aug 10 10:36:43 raspberrypi sudo[1320]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

Answer (score 1):

Your unit looks fairly good. From the status I don't understand why there are lines from `[sudo]`

```
raspberrypi sudo[1320]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/home/pi/pywork ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
raspberrypi sudo[1320]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
raspberrypi sudo[1320]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

It seems there is something opening a sudo session *(pam_unix(sudo:session))* and tries to write to a *tty* (standard output?). But on a starting service there is no *tty* (TTY=unknown) so you cannot output to it. Maybe this is from the option `-u` (unbuffered binary stdout and stderr) invoked with *python3*?

Also your "service" does not continue to run like a service in the background. It ended *inactive (dead)* regular with *(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)*. So I assume it is a oneshot.

Services are executed with root rights by default so I would omit `User=root`.

So for the first attempt I would suggest to try this unit:

```
[Unit]
Description=sendService
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 send.py
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/pywork

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Now I get [photo-screen](https://imgur.com/a/ujQ0rJK) seems to be better but still script start and exited

Comment: What does your script do? Seems it needs some environment that doesn't exist on startup.

Comment: this python script works quite like a server, but like I said before when I use command line to start it "sudo python3 send.py" it works like charm so there is no problem with script.

Comment: Like a server? Should it always run in the background? With `sudo` on the command line you have the user environment that isn't present on startup. Look at `man systemd.exec` what you can do to setup the needed environment. And is it possible that you show us the script? You can edit your question for this.